# Поиск и удаление символа в строке при вводе текста

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения, строки

написал функцию, которая не дает вписать символы не подоходящие под регулярное выражение в строку.

Но минус в том, что если я зажму какой-то "неправильный" символ и отпущу через несколько секунд, то удалится только последний,

Такая же ситуация будет, если я поставлю курсор где то посередине и начну вводить "неправильные" символы.

Как сделать, чтобы при отпускании клавиши, прошел полный поиск по всей строке и удаление лишнего из нее?

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  name = $(this).val();
  name_pattern = '^[А-Яа-яЁё]*$';
  result = name.search(name_pattern);
  console.log(result);
  console.log(name.length);
  if (result < 0) {
    $(this).val(name.slice(0, name.length - 1));
    console.log(name);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text'>
```

Answer (score 1):

А чем не устроил тупой replace?

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var name = $(this).val();
  name = name.replace(/[^А-Яа-яЁё]/g, '');
  $(this).val(name);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text'>
```

Comment: Начал вписывать буквы потом цифры, и строка без цифр начала пристыковываться к текущей, но не перезаписывать ее

Comment: Черт и в моем примере так же, если выводить с телефона,  простой андроид 7.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов В коде нет никакой пристыковки. Вы используете мой код или свою вольную интерпретацию его? Нажмите кнопку "Выболнить код" и убедитесь, что все работает

Comment: Так и сделал,  если есть возможность, проверьте сами с телефона. Введенные данные множатся,  но не перезаписываются

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов такой возможности нет. А если вместо `$(this).val()` писать `this.value`?